# R: Factor level in ggplot treated as continuous data set

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I am using a categorical variable to color the lines, labels, and ribbons in a plot created by ggplot. Numerical thresholds are used to distinguish three different categories, and those categories are assigned either green, blue, or red lines/labels/ribbons. What I have works well in most scenarios, but there is one scenario where it falls apart. If I have data that transitions from one category to another, and then back to the original, the data in the first and final group is treated as if it were continuous. A minimal reproducible example follows, but first I include two data sets in CSV format that are read into dataframes (a "good" set followed by a "bad" set):

GOOD DATA:

```
drug,dose,value,samples,conf,lower,upper
verapamil,1,72.56565,800,0.95,69.8194345,75.33907125
verapamil,2,72.44075,800,0.95,69.44212025,75.1824985
verapamil,3,70.79216,800,0.95,67.52461925,73.76032875
verapamil,4,68.91252,800,0.95,65.1242505,71.9545765
verapamil,5,66.91399,800,0.95,62.3466355,70.25188075
verapamil,6,65.07556,800,0.95,59.776704,68.484171
verapamil,7,63.52973,800,0.95,57.2319935,66.67006225
verapamil,8,62.22067,800,0.95,54.90753525,65.26015775
verapamil,9,60.65876,800,0.95,52.87391825,64.0331005
verapamil,10,59.57872,800,0.95,50.9498555,63.08050025
verapamil,15,56.44804,800,0.95,42.66295,73.614082
verapamil,20,55.23902,800,0.95,29.75458325,109.266985
verapamil,25,55.16381,800,0.95,23.006594,120.3280525
```

BAD DATA:

```
drug,dose,value,samples,conf,lower,upper
ranolazine,1,70.481,800,0.95,67.05068975,73.7571095
ranolazine,2,70.37064,800,0.95,66.865067,73.9150805
ranolazine,3,69.93621,800,0.95,66.70263375,74.0239275
ranolazine,4,69.53205,800,0.95,66.58873925,73.8851205
ranolazine,5,69.15334,800,0.95,66.0595545,73.833377
ranolazine,6,68.59902,800,0.95,65.4348675,73.7104295
ranolazine,7,68.09159,800,0.95,64.82512825,73.588261
ranolazine,8,67.53056,800,0.95,63.9937705,73.09860775
ranolazine,9,66.89892,800,0.95,63.253657,72.61998375
ranolazine,10,66.58314,800,0.95,62.4634455,71.94309325
ranolazine,15,67.00043,800,0.95,49.49385475,70.59155425
ranolazine,20,75.5989,800,0.95,33.52134225,86.43966325
ranolazine,25,88.64885,800,0.95,31.974256,104.275215
```

And the R script:

```
infile <-"good.csv"
#infile <-"bad.csv"
cidf <- read.csv(file = infile, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# prepare results for plotting
cidf[,c("value","lower","upper")]<-cidf[,c("value","lower","upper")]/1e3 # convert units

# assign value used to color lines, labels, and ribbons
for (row in 1:nrow(cidf)) {
  if(is.na(cidf$value[row])) {
    cidf$CiPA[row] = 2
  } else if (cidf$value[row] > 0.0689) {
    cidf$CiPA[row] = 0
  } else if (cidf$value[row] > 0.0579) {
    cidf$CiPA[row] = 1 
  } else cidf$CiPA[row] = 2
}
cidf$CiPA<-factor(cidf$CiPA, levels=c(2,1,0)) # THIS IS CAUSING THE WEIRD ISSUE WITH THE RANOLAZINE PLOT!
#cidf$CiPA<-factor(cidf$CiPA, levels=c(0))
#cidf$CiPA<-factor(cidf$CiPA, levels=c(1))

#cidf <- droplevels(cidf)
#cidf$CiPA <- as.numeric(as.character(cidf$CiPA))

# data frame of drug labels
newdf<-aggregate(dose ~ drug, data=cidf, max)
colnames(newdf)<-c("drug","max")
newdf<-merge(cidf,newdf,by.x="drug",by.y="drug",all=TRUE)
newdf<-newdf[newdf$dose==newdf$max,]
tofix<-which(is.na(newdf$value))
for(fixi in tofix)
  newdf[fixi,"value"]<-mean(as.numeric(newdf[fixi, c("lower","upper")]))

figfile<-"plot.pdf"
pdf(figfile, width=8, height=4.5)

p<-ggplot(cidf, aes(dose, value, group=interaction(drug, CiPA))) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("2" = "#e82929", "1"="#337cb4", "0"="#44ae52")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("2" = "#e82929", "1"="#337cb4", "0"="#44ae52"), name="fill") + 
  geom_line(aes(color=CiPA)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper, fill = CiPA), alpha=0.3) + 
  geom_text(data=newdf, aes(label=drug, color=CiPA), hjust=-0.2, vjust=0.5, size=3, show.legend=F)  + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,max(cidf$dose)*1.2)) + 
  xlab(~"Concentration (\u00D7"~C[max]*")") + 
  ylab(~"qNet ("*mu*"C/"*mu*"F)") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position="none")

x11(title="Plot")   # switch dev from pdf to x11
show(p)                              # show the plot in a window
while(names(dev.cur()) !='pdf'){     # dev changes from x11 back to pdf when window is closed
  print(names(dev.cur()))            # this conditional is required, otherwise window closes immediately
  Sys.sleep(1)
}

print(p)

dev.off()
```

I am working in Ubuntu, so if you are not you can remove the X11 plot show. Using the "good" data set, the plot is still not quite right. I have to manipulate the data to add some extra points at thresholds where colors change (I did not want to include that function in this example as it is large and isn't directly involved with the problem at hand). When I do so the plot comes out as below:

[image: Good plot with updated data]

We travel from one categorical variable, then to the next, and finally the third. However, using the "bad" data set, the issue is that we travel from one categorical variable, to another, but then back to the first. In this case the first and third blocks of data are treated as if they are continuous instead of discrete. This is more easily seen when you change the factor levels from `c(2,1,0)` to `c(1)` or `c(0)`. What I end up with is this:

[image: Bad plot]

A line is added connecting the data point at Cmax = 5 to Cmax = 15, treating these two discrete sets as if they are continuous. Then the middle set of data with the different categorical variable is by itself, not connected to the adjacent data points. This is clearly not what I am looking for and I cannot figure out where I am going wrong. If I try to use numerical values, I end up with the error:

```
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
```

Dropping levels also did not work. I am not sure if there is a simple solution here, but I expect that there would be. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

---

EDIT: The output of dput(cidf) was requested. For the "good" data I receive:

```
> dput(cidf)
structure(list(drug = c("verapamil", "verapamil", "verapamil", 
"verapamil", "verapamil", "verapamil", "verapamil", "verapamil", 
"verapamil", "verapamil", "verapamil", "verapamil", "verapamil"
), dose = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 15L, 20L, 
25L), value = c(0.07256565, 0.07244075, 0.07079216, 0.06891252, 
0.06691399, 0.06507556, 0.06352973, 0.06222067, 0.06065876, 0.05957872, 
0.05644804, 0.05523902, 0.05516381), samples = c(800L, 800L, 
800L, 800L, 800L, 800L, 800L, 800L, 800L, 800L, 800L, 800L, 800L
), conf = c(0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 
0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95), lower = c(0.0698194345, 0.06944212025, 
0.06752461925, 0.0651242505, 0.0623466355, 0.059776704, 0.0572319935, 
0.05490753525, 0.05287391825, 0.0509498555, 0.04266295, 0.02975458325, 
0.023006594), upper = c(0.07533907125, 0.0751824985, 0.07376032875, 
0.0719545765, 0.07025188075, 0.068484171, 0.06667006225, 0.06526015775, 
0.0640331005, 0.06308050025, 0.073614082, 0.109266985, 0.1203280525
), CiPA = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2", "1", "0"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-13L), class = "data.frame")
```

And for the "bad" data I get:

```
> dput(cidf)
structure(list(drug = c("ranolazine", "ranolazine", "ranolazine", 
"ranolazine", "ranolazine", "ranolazine", "ranolazine", "ranolazine", 
"ranolazine", "ranolazine", "ranolazine", "ranolazine", "ranolazine"
), dose = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 15L, 20L, 
25L), value = c(0.070481, 0.07037064, 0.06993621, 0.06953205, 
0.06915334, 0.06859902, 0.06809159, 0.06753056, 0.06689892, 0.06658314, 
0.06700043, 0.0755989, 0.08864885), samples = c(800L, 800L, 800L, 
800L, 800L, 800L, 800L, 800L, 800L, 800L, 800L, 800L, 800L), 
    conf = c(0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 
    0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95), lower = c(0.06705068975, 0.066865067, 
    0.06670263375, 0.06658873925, 0.0660595545, 0.0654348675, 
    0.06482512825, 0.0639937705, 0.063253657, 0.0624634455, 0.04949385475, 
    0.03352134225, 0.031974256), upper = c(0.0737571095, 0.0739150805, 
    0.0740239275, 0.0738851205, 0.073833377, 0.0737104295, 0.073588261, 
    0.07309860775, 0.07261998375, 0.07194309325, 0.07059155425, 
    0.08643966325, 0.104275215), CiPA = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("2", 
    "1", "0"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This is a lot for me to follow. I hope there are others more intrepid than me. Would it make any sense to share the output of `dput(cidf)` in the two cases so we can skip the prep steps, or would that miss the point of your question?

Comment: @JonSpring, no it would not miss the point. The data only matters in the "bad" data set because the data is assigned a categorical variable that travels from 0 -> 1 -> 0, and the factoring of the categorical variable treats the two sets of data assigned 0 as if they are continuous rather than discrete. I will edit the question now with that output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this resolve your issue? I added a variable that separates each change in CiPA, even if it's going back to one already used. That way it doesn't connect non-contiguous sections which share a CiPA level.

EDIT - here showing full code that works verbatim on my computer.

EDIT #2 - added adjusted line for text to ignore the `CiPA_grp` grouping variable which `newdf` won't have. `aes(group = 1)` in that layer will specify that it should put all elements (just one in actuality) in the same group, rather than looking to the `CiPA_grp` variable for that.

```
library(dplyr)
cidf %>%   # using the "bad" version
  arrange(drug, dose) %>%
  group_by(drug) %>%
  mutate(CiPA_grp = cumsum(as.numeric(CiPA) != lag(as.numeric(CiPA), default = Inf))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

ggplot(aes(dose, value, group=interaction(drug, CiPA_grp))) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("2" = "#e82929", "1"="#337cb4", "0"="#44ae52")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("2" = "#e82929", "1"="#337cb4", "0"="#44ae52"), name="fill") + 
  geom_line(aes(color=CiPA)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper, fill = CiPA), alpha=0.3) + 
  geom_text(data=newdf, aes(label=drug, color=CiPA, group = 1), hjust=-0.2, vjust=0.5, size=3, show.legend=F)  +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,max(cidf$dose)*1.2)) + 
  xlab(~"Concentration (\u00D7"~C[max]*")") + 
  ylab(~"qNet ("*mu*"C/"*mu*"F)") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

Comment: From the look of the plot, this is exactly what I am looking for. However, I am having trouble getting it to actually work. I am pretty sure the dangling pipe after `ungroup()` is called needs to be removed. And in the context of the minimal example above, there is no data frame `cidf_bad` nor column `CiPA_grp`. And I also think the ggplot call is missing the dataframe. I haven't been able to reproduce your result just yet, so if you could clean up your post such that it integrates with the minimal example above, I would be more than happy to accept this as the answer. Many thanks!

Comment: Ah, I think you piped the data frame directly into ggplot?

Comment: Yes, it gets fed into the first term, i.e. `data`

Comment: I am pretty sure I have a handle on most of this now aside from one thing, the variable that you added, namely CiPA_grp. I created a new data frame via `cidf_bad<-cidf` before the piped calls but still get an error in interaction that CiPA_grp is not found. Is this supposed to be a new column in the data frame?

Comment: edited to show exact code that works on my system. I like piping wrangled data directly into ggplot, but it's also fine to save that data into a dataframe and to reference that dataframe  with `ggplot(data = wrangled_data, ...`; that's also helpful for how you're referencing the data frame in coord_cartesian, to help keep them aligned.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I have never used pipes before in R. I was able to produce the plot above by using `+ ggsave(figfile)` , but I would still like to be able to show the plot. By piping into ggplot, the plot itself is never assigned to `p`. Would I have to pipe into the `show()` as well in order to get that to work?

Comment: If you want to assign to p, you can add `p <-` before any of the piped steps or `-> p` at the end of them all. If you want to assign the plot and show the side effect of printing it in one step, you can also use `(p <- all_the %>% wrangling %>% and %>% plotting %>% stuff %>% here)`.

Comment: One last question. you mention in your edit that you comment out the `geom_text` line because the data is not provided in the original question. It actually is, but it's a separate data frame, namely `newdf`. I think this errors out because of the piping from `cidf` and I am not sure what the workaround would be to get this label back from `newdf`?

Comment: Fixed in answer. That layer's data doesn't have the `CiPA_grp` variable referred to in the global `aes()` defined in `ggplot(aes(...`, but doesn't need it, so we can tell it to use `aes(group = 1)` to skip it.